# Floating number comparison using BC

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

**Background**

Beginner here trying to learn some Bash basics.

My question is my attempt at modifying an existing textbook example to include simple input validation. The validation works if one or more inputs are inappropriate but when all three inputs are appropriate, I instead get a syntax error warning and then an answer.

Code is at the end, but below are my thoughts. Appreciate any corrections wherever they are wrong.
Much thanks.

**Thoughts**

- I have three conditions to check for. If any one of them fails, a message is displayed and the program terminates. This works. However, if all 3 conditions are met, then I receive a syntax error.
- I thought the error might be related to expansion so I manually ran the commands and supplied hard inputs using the command line. E.g. `bc <<< "0.5 > 0"` and these seemed to work as intended.
- Subsequently, it seems that my problems only arise when I involve the $interest variable with its decimal points. However, I used BC because my understanding is that Bash only does Integers. What else have I missed out?

**Code**

```
# loan-calc: script to calculate monthly loan payments
#               formulae may be mathematically wrong, example copied from textbook
#               reference only for bash scripting, not math

PROGNAME="${0##*/}"

usage () {
    cat <<- EOF
    Usage: $PROGNAME PRINCIPAL INTEREST MONTHS

    Where:
    PRINCIPAL is the amount of the loan.
    INTEREST is the APR as a number (7% = 0.07)
    MONTHS is the length of the loan's term.

    EOF
}

read -p "Enter principal amount > " principal

read -p "Enter interest rate (E.g. 7.5% = 0.075) > " interest

read -p "Enter term length in months > " months

# Principal, interest rate, and months must be more than 0.
if (( "$principal <= 0" | bc )) || (( "$months <= 0" | bc )) || (( "$interest <= 0" | bc )); then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

result=$(bc <<- EOF
    scale = 10
    i = $interest / 12
    p = $principal
    n = $months
    p * ((i * ((1 + i) ^ n)) / (((1 + i) ^ n) - 1))
EOF
)

printf "%0.2f\n" $result
```

Comment: What *is* the error?

Comment: One of the basics is to not use `bash` for this kind of program.

Comment: Hi chepner, noted your comment. I just happen to be learning bash scripting and this was one of the examples which I came across and am trying to add some modifications of my own to test my understanding and for learning purposes. When I do get better, of course one of the next steps would be to be able to decide which tool is better for a job as you proposed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)

`(( 1 | bc ))` does not pipe 1 into `bc`.  When you are evaluating expressions inside of `(( expression ))`, `|` is the bitwise OR operator, ***not a pipe***.

`(( bc ))` evaluates to 1 every time, so all of your conditional tests are just OR'ing the number with 1, *not* piping the number into `bc`.

Your expression inside of the parentheses should be the output from echoing the mathematical string into `bc` using a pipe, e.g. `(( $(echo "$variable <= 0"| bc) ))`.

This can be wrapped in a named function so the `if` statement is more readable.

```sh
notValid() {
    (( $(echo "$1 <= 0" | bc) ))
}

# Principal, interest rate, and months must be more than 0.
if  notValid "$principal" || notValid "$months" || notValid "$interest"; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: dwmorrin, thank you for your explanation. The `$(echo...)` part is still not quite second nature to me so I'll need more practice and to be careful. Much appreciated!